# jQuery slide and stop issues: animated element freezes with quick mouse movement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is [Zi JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJnHH/). In order to replicate my issue you have to hover over the link that says 'javascript', then mouseout that, then mouseback in. If you do this before the animation is complete, the pink slidedown `#subMenu` will freeze midway through sliding. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I have tried some `.stop()`s , but i really don't want the animation to re-start every time you mouseenter or leave the `.navLink` . The animation should begin from where it left off. In other words, if the pink section is halfway down, and a slideDown() gets executed, the pink should not dissappear and then slide down, it should slide down from where it is.

Thanks!!

JS:

```
 $('header#subHeader').hide();
    $('.navLink').hover(function () {
        if ($(this).children('div').length > 0) {
            var subMenu = $(this).find('.subMenu').html();
            $('header#subHeader').empty().append('<div>' + subMenu + '</div>').stop().slideDown();
        } else {
            $('header#subHeader').stop().slideUp();
        }
    });
    $('hgroup:first').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $('header#subHeader').slideUp();
    });
```

Comment: This fiddle is updated to have really big slidedown area: http://jsfiddle.net/bJnHH/1/

Comment: @BradM `.finish()` totally makes things worse, i dont want it to ever snap to a position like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `stop(true, true)` to complete the pending animation (jumping to the end) as well so that you dont get that mid way effect.

```
 $('header#subHeader').hide();
    $('.navLink').hover(function () {
        if ($(this).children('div').length > 0) {
            var subMenu = $(this).find('.subMenu').html();
            $('header#subHeader').empty().append('<div>' + subMenu + '</div>').stop(true, true).slideDown();
        } else {
            $('header#subHeader').stop(true, true).slideUp();
        }
    });
    $('hgroup:first').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $('header#subHeader').slideUp();
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yyLL6/)**

> .stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )

```
clearQueue
Type: Boolean
A Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as well. Defaults to false.
jumpToEnd
Type: Boolean
A Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false.
```

Try `animate` instead of `slide` height for the desired effect to get a feel of resuming the slide up/ down animation:

```
var slideUpSettings = {
             height: '0px'
         };

var slideDownSettings = {
             height: '20px'
         };


 $('.navLink').hover(function () {
     var $header = $('header#subHeader');
     if ($(this).children('div').length > 0) {

         var subMenu = $(this).find('.subMenu').html();
         $header.empty().append('<div>' + subMenu + '</div>').stop().animate(slideDownSettings, 500);
     } else {

         $header.stop().animate(slideUpSettings, 500);
     }
 });
 $('#subHeader').on('mouseenter', function () {
     $(this).stop().animate(slideDownSettings, 500);
 });


 $('hgroup:first').on('mouseleave', function () {
     $('header#subHeader').stop().animate(slideUpSettings, 500);
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L56CW/)**

Comment: ya, but it jumps to the start then, if you go in and out really fast, it only animates the slideDown()

Comment: Then check for is(':animated')

Comment: But what will that get me, is there a way to stop the animation without reverting to the state before the animation?

Comment: You know what i believe you cant do with slideDown. probably animate might help. Either set up animate of height and calculate the remaining height form what it is currently. or position the menu as absolute and specify top to it. haven't tried both. But theory..

Comment: @sherlock i will login back and see i can get one working for you and update here...

Comment: ooh, thats awesome, but can you get it to not slideup when you hover the pink section?

Comment: @sherlock here you go.. http://jsfiddle.net/szAbx/. Just remove the duration `1000` on animate if you think it is too slow. You can fiddle around.

Comment: OMG you are like the most helpful person ever.

Comment: @sherlock nevermind :) . I just cleaned up the code a bit as well.