# Sliding div stops and goes further

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs on top of eachother. One div (gray one) is sliding in from the top over the other one (black one).

When you place your mouse over the black div the gray one slides out of view.

When you place your mouse over the gray div the gray one slides out of view also but it stops for a moment when the mouse is at the bottom of that div and than goes further.

**Here is the html**

```
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/logo.css"> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".carosel,.logo").hover(function(){
    $('.logo').stop().animate({'top': '-150px'}, 1000);
}, function(){
    $('.logo').stop().animate({'top': '0px'}, 1000);
});
});
</script> 

<script>
$(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
$('.logo').hide().delay(1000).show().animate({'top': "0px"}, 1000);
}); 
</script> 

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="carosel"> </div>
<div class="logo"> bla bla mekker mekker </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Here is the css**

```
.container {
height: 800px;
width: 800px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
background-color: red;
}

.logo {
height: 150px;
width: 800px;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #000000;
position:absolute;
top:-150px; 
}

.carosel {
height: 250px;
width: 800px;
background-color: #202020;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
}
```

As you can see I am new at jQuery so I hope you guys can help me with this one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vFJ27/1/

Comment: @ Viridis, Thanks for putting the code on JSFiddle for me. :)

Comment: I can't replicate the issue you are getting. What browser are you having this problem in?

Comment: I can replicate the issue, but i have no clue what you actually want to do xD. It has to hide when you hover over the grey one only?

Comment: I think I see what he is saying; it is quite subtle.  With fast movement, the animation freezes.  Please see this question for your answer: [jQuery slide and stop issues: animated element freezes with quick mouse movement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354086/jquery-slide-and-stop-issues-animated-element-freezes-with-quick-mouse-movement)

Comment: FF and IE. It is no big deal but when the bottom of the gray div is sliding at the place where the mouse is than the slide effect is getting distorted in some way.

Comment: @user1477388 Is it when you hover over the black, it starts moving, then you move the mouse over the gray it stutters? Is that the issue?

Comment: This is because there is `stop()` in there. Every time you 'hover' over the div, it will `stop()` first, and then start a new animation. Check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/vFJ27/3/. Its not what you want, but it doesnt have it because there is no `stop()`

Comment: I need the .stop() otherwise the gray div keeps bouncing up and down.

Comment: @easyrider is this satisfactory? The effect seems minimized: http://jsfiddle.net/vFJ27/4/

Comment: @user1477388. Nop, still has the stutter effect

Comment: It doesnt need `stop()` i think if you do `$(".logo").hover()` instead of `$(".carosel,.logo").hover()` because you don't want it to happen when you hover over `.carosel`. It only bounces if you quickly go in and out because it starts queueing the actions ... give me a minute to check if i can get rid of that haha

Comment: @Viridis, I also want to slide the gray div when I hover over the black div.

Comment: No clue. The stutter happens because while it's dragging up, your mouse suddenly hovers over another element, triggering the 'stop()' again. There seems to be a few 'solutions' for checking if an element is being animated ... but i can't really get them to work properly. :S. Good luck on your quest ^__^

Comment: @Viridis I think this is what he wants (see my answer below).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is put the .logo in the .carousel.  See my update and you will find no 'shuttering'.

```
<div class="carosel">
     <div class="logo">bla bla mekker mekker</div>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".carosel").hover(function(){
        $('.logo').stop().animate({'top': '-150px'}, 1000);
    }, function(){
        $('.logo').stop().animate({'top': '0px'}, 1000);
    });
    $('.logo').hide().delay(1000).show().animate({'top': "0px"}, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vFJ27/6/

Comment: yeah this seems better than the original. though, if you hover in and out quickly, you'll see that the stutter is actually still there.

Comment: I was not able to see any shuttering, and if it is there, I doubt it's possible to solve (nor would I be interested in solving it since it, if it's there, it is so miniscule).

Comment: Turns out i'm actually retarded ... There needs to be the `stop()` in there, and for some reason i'm trying to fix that it's there ... it was never an issue.. i'm just stupid. You were right all along.

Comment: Many thanks user1477388. This was the solution, and yet so simple thanks again. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/vFJ27/6/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the Solution you are wanting : [Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uy4FY/2/)

To get this to work you will need to update your **jQuery Version to 1.8.3** (for the `always` callback function of the Animate function)

(**Avoid 1.9.1** as the following check will break `!$(".carosel").is(":hover") && !$(".logo").is(":hover")`. This is due to a Bug that was corrected again in jQuery 1.10.1)

Here is the example code :

```
var hideRunning = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".carosel").hover(function() {
        if (!hideRunning) {
            hideRunning = true;
            $('.logo').stop().animate({'top': '-150px'}, {
                duration:1000,
                always:function() {
                    hideRunning = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }, function() {
        if (!$(".carosel").is(":hover") && !$(".logo").is(":hover")) {
                $('.logo').stop().animate({'top': '0px'}, 1000);
        }
    });
});

$(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
    $('.logo').hide().delay(1000).show().animate({'top': "0px"}, 1000);
});
```

Now when you hover over either div, it checks to see if the animation is currently running, if it is then it will **not** call the `.stop().animate()` again.

Also when you hover-out of a div it will check if the either div is currently hovered, if they are then it will **not** call the `.stop().animate()` again.

This is simply removing duplicate calls to the `.stop()` function.

Comment: I can not use jQuery Version to 1.8.3. I need to use jQuery Version to 1.6.4 because I am running a 3D carosel script that does not work with higher jQuery versions.

I seens that user1477388 got the problem solved, He just puts the gray div into the black div. Just super.